# Parent program's working directory is not searched for DLLs when child program is started with CreateProcess

Tags: c, windows, winapi, createprocess, win32-process

I have a very weird problem. I am working on a C program under **Windows** that writes data to the temp directory. It uses [GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to generate a unique name. The data is actually an **exe** that I start with [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after the data is written to the temp file. For `lpCurrentDirectory` param I use `NULL` so to use the current working directory of the parent program becomes a working directory of the child one. There are all the needed DLLs.

On most computers (XP, 2003, 7, 8) everything works as expected. But on one particular **Windows 7** I get exception when the child program starts. Very strangely but if I move all the needed DLLs to the temp directory, everything works as expected.

Hmm, so why the parent program's working directory is not searched for the DLLs?

Many thanks.

Comment: It does not have to be "current directory" exactly. The fact you state is that the problem is a missing dependency. Windows uses [DLL Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications) to located the DLLs. This is where you check from that dependencies are on the search path. Current directories are something you can trace/log and make sure that they are are you expect them to be.

Comment: @RomanR., yes, I know I am missing a DLL. The question is why Windows doesn't search in the parent program working directory?!

Comment: My guess would be because you expect current dir to be parent app's direct and it is in fact a different one.

Comment: @RomanR., I set `lpCurrentDirectory` to `NULL` and the documentation says in such case the child's process working directory is set to the parent's one. Strange. And this behavior is only on one machine. All the rest work fine. Very strange.

Comment: `NULL` gets you parent's current dir, not parent's application binary dir - this is my point.

Comment: The DLLs are in the parent's current dir.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov: There is a **BIG** difference between the parent's **current working directory** (which is what `CreateProcess()` inherits) and the directory where the parent **exe file resides**. The CWD is **dynamic**, it can (and usually does) change value during the process's lifetime, so it is very likely **NOT** pointing where you think it is pointing at the exact moment that `CreateProcess()` is called. You don't seem to be understanding that distinction.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov: If you want the child process to look in the parent's **installation directory** rather than the parent's **current working directory**, then you need to either pass the parent's **installation directory** as `lpCurrentDirectory` to `CreateProcess()` (even that is not a guarantee), or else pass the parent directory as a command-line parameter to the child process and then make the child load the DLLs dynamically from that path at runtime (or at least call `SetDllDirectory()` or `AddDllDirectory()` on itself) after it has started running.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, "You don't seem to be understanding that distinction." - what makes you think so? In my question and the comments I only talk about the current working directory of the parent process (which by accident is the directory where the parent exe files resides :))

Comment: There is a security option in Windows that prohibits loading DLLs from the current directory.  That might be set on the machine in question.  The KB number to search on for more information is 2264107.

Comment: Why not just pass the proper current directory for child process explicitly to make sure that current directory is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original question asked why the child process does not inherit the working directory of the parent. Well, if you pass NULL to CreateProcess then the new process will inherit the working directory of the parent process at the time that the call to CreateProcess is made. The documentation makes this quite clear and there are no surprises here. CreateProcess behaves precisely as advertised.

The edited question concentrates on DLL search. It's not easy to answer this new take on the question from this information. The best thing to do is to run the program under the profile mode of Dependency Walker. This should reveal what is wrong. You may well find that the problem is not at all what you expect it to be.

And for future reference, I recommend that you include full details of any errors when you ask a question. You stated that an exception was raised but really you need to supply the full details of any exceptions.

Comment: Hi David and thanks for your time. If you read my question a second time, you will see that I have described that when I move all DLLs to the temp dir, the child program starts normally. Why (and only on this particular Windows 7 machine) the current directory is not searched? The current directory (the one the parent program is running in) has all the required DLLs.

Comment: I don't need to read it again. The exe will find the dlls when they are in the same directory as it, your temp dir.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to offend you. Isn't the current working directory also searched?

Comment: Please, check this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx. Even with **SafeDllSearchMode** the current directory is searched.

Comment: Perhaps some other version of the DLLs are found first. It's crazy to rely on the working directory for your DLL search. The question that I answered was: *Hmm, so the child program's current working directory was
not set to the parent's one?!* You appear to be asking a different question now.

Comment: Anyway, I updated my answer to better match the updated question.

Comment: Yes, I see now it is not a good idea to rely on the parent's working directory since it is searched after the system paths when `SafeDllSearchMode` is enabled which is by default. Thank you for you time.